# How do I optimize this jQuery code to match ids

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I have this piece of code:

```
$('#sh1').hover(function(){$('#tip1').toggle()});
$('#sh2').hover(function(){$('#tip2').toggle()});
$('#sh3').hover(function(){$('#tip3').toggle()});
$('#sh4').hover(function(){$('#tip4').toggle()});
```

etc.

The number of elements can be 30-40. Obviously this is not the right way to do such thing. But how do I make it right? With the "for" loop or "if" condition or regex or what?

Markup will go like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="sh1"></div>
    <div id="sh2"></div>
    <div id="sh3"></div>
    <div id="sh4"></div>
</div>
<div class="tip" id="tip1">text</div>
<div class="tip" id="tip2">text</div>
<div class="tip" id="tip3">text</div>
<div class="tip" id="tip4">text</div>
```

Comment: iterate in a while loop which test the existence of the element

Comment: Add a descriptive class (e.g. `class="hover"`) and use this for your selector `$(".hover").hover(...)`

Comment: can you post your HTML ..just  `#sh1`  and `#tip1` is fine

Comment: We need to see HTML before this can be optimized. It'll give us a good idea as to what can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BXZ4k/)**

You can do it with a classic `for` loop, here is another simple solution:

```
$(function () {
    $('[id^="sh"]').hover(function () {
        var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('sh', '');
        $('[id="tip' + index + '"]').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of this:  var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('sh', '');
        $('[id="tip' + index + '"]').toggle();    use this:  $(this).toggle();

Comment: @KamilT `this` will point to current element (`#sh1`), I want to toggle another element (`#tip1`).

Answer (score 0):

Using attribute selector (i.e., **[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**), you can achieve

### Example:

Assuming `sh` and `tip` are div's

```
$('div[id^="sh"]').hover(function(){$('div[id^="tip"]').toggle()});
```

### Updated:

```
$('div[id^="sh"]').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = parseInt(/\d+/.exec(id), 10);
    $("#tip"+id).toggle();
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/v83rk/)**

Comment: That will toggle **every** div starting with tip on hover.

Comment: @Zenith Ooops, perfect catch `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a classfor each element you want to cycle throuhg and add:

```
$(".YourClass").).hover(function(){$(this).toggle();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a class to each element you want to trigger and the use it as selector:

A thing like this:

```
$('.YourClass').hover(function(){$(this).toggle()});
```

Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

- use delegated events if all these elements lie in one parent element. you could bind that hover event to the parent.
- Use classes to refer to elements. Refer `#sh1,#sh2,etc` with a single `.sh` and `#tip1,#tip2,etc` with a class called `.tip`.
- if the `tip` group lies within `sh` group use jquery's traversal techniques to navigate to that element.

Beyond this optimization with regards to performance can depend only on the markup.